# Hash different, is it safe?

Tags: tail, hashsum

The first time I downloaded Tails image which is with different sha256sum than the webpage giving, so I downloaded it once again and this time it is correct. Then I unpakeged all the files inside the 2 images with WinRAR, and check each files, all the hashes are the same with each other, so what makes differences with the 2 images (.iso), and is it safe to use the one with the incorrect sha256?

Comment: no...the one with the incorrect sha256 is obviously corrupt in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

(This doesn't appear to be on topic, it has nothing particular to do with *nices)

No it's not "safe", in that it's been identified as corrupted.  Many things could make the hash different.  It could have been an error in the download that affected the archive package only somehow.  No matter how trivial, it's not worth the risk (at the very least you may be wasting a lot of time).  The download was somehow corrupted, the only way you could possibly confirm that it was actually OK would be to have a good copy to check against, once you have a good copy, why would you want to use the corrupted one?  Delete the corrupted copy an move on.

The hash doesn't really show that the files are safe, it validates that they were not corrupted in download, that's all.  You don't want to waste your time with corrupted downloads, even if the difference is in fact trivial.  You don't even want to waste your time figuring out that it's trivial, unless you are studying hashes.